# Boolean function as input parameter

Tags: c++, c++11, lambda, signature

I want to write a method which performs some action until a termination criterion becomes true. This termination criterion should be given by the user, and it can be any criterion.

I was thinking about passing a function with return type boolean (possibly a closure) to the method and call it as the condition of a while loop.

In Python, this would be

```
class Example:

    def doSomething(self, amIDone):
        while not amIDone():
            something()
        return
```

How can I express this in C++11?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

You could make your function a template and let it accept any callable object that returns a `bool`. For instance:

```
template<typename P>
void doSomething(P&& p)
{
    while (p())
    {
        something();
    }
}
```

This is how you could invoke it by passing a lambda, for instance:

```
int main()
{
    // Possibly pass a more clever lambda here...
    doSomething([] () { return true; });
}
```

Of course you could pass a regular functor instead of a lambda:

```
struct my_functor
{
    // Possibly write a more clever call operator here...
    bool operator () ()
    {
        return true;
    }
};

int main()
{
    doSomething(my_functor());
}
```

A function pointer is also an option:

```
// Possibly use a more clever function than this one...
bool my_predicate()
{
    return true;
}

int main()
{
    doSomething(my_predicate);
}
```

If you have reasons for not making your function a template (for instance, because it is a `virtual` member function of some class), you could use `std::function`:

```
void doSomething(std::function<bool()> p)
{
    while (p())
    {
        something();
    }
}
```

All the examples above will work equally well with `std::function`, but [this will certainly cost you some run-time overhead](http://www.drdobbs.com/cpp/efficient-use-of-lambda-expressions-and/232500059) (which may be irrelevant for your use cases, though).

Comment: The callable should be required to return a boolean value.

Comment: @cls: I thought that was implicit, but OK, I made the explicit. Thank you

Answer (score 2):

you could do this using `std::function` from the `<functional>` headers.

The predicate is looking like this:

```
bool predicate()
{
    ...
    return false;
}
```

And this is your class using the predicate functor

```
struct A
{
    void test (std::function<bool(void)> func)
    {
        while( func() )
        {   
            perform();
        }
    }
}
```

and you can call it this way:

```
A a;
a.test(predicate);
```

In this example I took the function `bool predicate()` as a predicate. But a lambda function or a class defining `bool operator()` would have worked the same.